# How to wrap HTML in JavaScript so as to iterate through a dictionary and add to a flex container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have this code:

```
      <ul className="flex-container"> {
            Object.keys(this.state.filestest).forEach(function(key) {
            <div className="Tile">
                *do stuff
            </div>
            });
        }
        </ul>
```

"filestest" is a String to String dictionary. All I want to do is be able to iterate through filestest, and add a div with className "Tile" for each item in the dictionary. The above code I wrote gives an error on the semi-colon, and other ways I try to write it doesn't work. I think this involves jQuery or something but I'm not familiar with jQuery. (I also need access to both the dictionary's keys and values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reactjs you'd do something like this (note the map instead of forEach):

```
// inside your react component:
render() {
  return (
      <ul className="flex-container"> {
            Object.keys(this.state.filestest).map(function(key) {
               return (<div className="Tile">
                {key}
               </div>)
            });
        }
        </ul>
  )
}
```